# http-mock-adapter Dio Assertion failed: "Could not find mocked route matching request for

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, dio

I'm trying to mock my Dio client with http-mock-adapter on put method and error method but I get this errors:

> Exception: Assertion failed: "Could not find mocked route matching request for POST /onboard/answer { data: {"pageId":"1"},

> Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: {message: Some beautiful error!}

I found this issue https://githubmemory.com/repo/lomsa-dev/http-mock-adapter/issues/96?page=2 but I didn't solve my problem. Below is the code

```
main() {
  final dio = Dio(BaseOptions());
  final dioAdapter = DioAdapter(dio: dio);
  dio.httpClientAdapter = dioAdapter;

  final service = NetworkService(dio);

  test("should return a DioError", () async {
    const path = "/onboard/page-date/0/lastAnswerId";
    final dioError = DioError(
      error: {'message': 'Some beautiful error!'},
      requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: path),
      response: Response(
        statusCode: 404,
        requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: path),
      ),
      type: DioErrorType.response,
    );
    dioAdapter.onGet(path, (server) {
      server.throws(404, dioError);
    });
    final result = await service.getOnboardingAnswer("lastAnswerId");
    expect(result, isA<OnboardModel>());
  });


  final answerModel = AnswerModel(pageId: "1");

  test("should return 200", () async {
    const path = "/onboard/answer";
    dioAdapter.onPost(path, (server) {
      server.reply(200, 200);
    });
    final result = await service.postOnboardingAnswer(answerModel);
    expect(result, isA<int>());
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `final dioAdapter = DioAdapter(dio: dio);`

use `final dioAdapter = DioAdapter(dio: dio, matcher: const UrlRequestMatcher());` this line only match passed URL not entire http request, so it should work on your case

in this [example from official lib](https://github.com/lomsa-dev/http-mock-adapter/blob/main/example/main.dart) your default adapter using **FullHttpRequestMatcher** which means that it will match your entire request including passed POST parameter

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Dio fails because it tries to match route with the exact data payload you are sending.

If you don't care about the actual data being sent you can use `Matchers.any` from `http-mock-adapter` lib:

```
dioAdapter.onPost(url, (server) {
  server.reply(200, 200);
}, data: Matchers.any);
```